# RequestBody + JSON

Tags: java, json, spring

I have problem with convert JSON to Java class.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/add", method = POST)
    public void add(@RequestBody NoteModel note) {
        System.out.println(note.getTitle());
    }
```

**JSON**

```
{
    title : "Title",
    text : "Text"
}
```

**NoteModel**

```
public class NoteModel {
    private String title;
    private String text;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

So, when I send json to the controller, Controller see same url, but can't deserialize JSON to Java (I think). Because, when I try, to send JSON - `{ title : "Title" }`, and controller wait argument - `@RequestBody String note`, it can easily display it.

I'm try to do, what was in https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/14/posting-json-to-spring-mvc-controller/ and include adapter in servlet.xml, but was the same effect.

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url : window.location.pathname,
        data : JSON.stringify({
            title : $("#titleId").val(),
            text : $("#textId").val()
        }),
        success: function () {
            $("#titleId").val("");
            $("#textId").val("");
        }
    })
```

Comment: How do you send the JSON? Did you set the content-type to `application/json`?

Comment: yes, the content type is, wait some time, I add ajax code

Comment: have you added dependency for json in pom.xml?

Comment: yes, mapper-asl and also core-asl

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.4</version>
  </dependency>     also  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20151123</version>
  </dependency>   and try once

Comment: did not helped, thinking change json data, through String

Comment: Not familiar with AJAX, but are you sure about `contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",`? Shouldn't those be _two_ attributes?

Comment: when I fight with this problem, also, I remove 'charset'.
So, shoud or shouldn't, I tried two way.

Comment: Are you sure `url : window.location.pathname` is right? Should it not point to the add endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Add @RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/add", method = POST, **produces = "application/json"**)

Comment: added, but again, I have same effect

Comment: Sorry earlier I misunderstood the question. Send the data as below. data : {
            title : $("#titleId").val(),
            text : $("#textId").val()
        }

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added content-type to "application/json" in header of your request.

Comment: I try to do it, but it's not change situation
https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/14/posting-json-to-spring-mvc-controller/

Answer (score 0):

how to catch the problem:
Send the String to your controller and try to create your object. Put breakpoint to objectMapper.readValue() and check what is the exactly problem;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/add", method = POST)
public void add(@RequestBody String note) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    NoteModel noteModel = objectMapper.readValue(result, NoteModel.class);
}
```

I think that there is some conflict between default ObjectMapper and JSON mapper logic.